Inrush spike current sensing

Image source: DCC-EX Model Railroading - IBT_2 BTS7960 Motor Board - IBT_2 schematic


Image source: Infineon - BTS 7960 Datasheet

I have a brushed dc motor connected to a ibt_2 h bridge.
The ibt_2 consists of 2 bts7960 half bridges and a sn74ahc244dw.
The motor is attached to a ball screw and I would like to use the current sensing feature of the bts7960 as a limit switch.
The problem I'm having is the inrush current spike is triggering my “limit switch.” This also sometimes happens when reversing direction.
Is there a simple way to smooth/filter the in rush spike and still use the stall current as a limit switch?
Power supply is 24v 6.5 amp

A ramped startup could work; what is your control signal?

What happens if you bypass the bridge and power it from a DC supply. Does the limit switch still trip?

I’m sending a pwm signal using linuxcnc. Is that what you mean by control signal?

I added an image of a schematic but if you need other information, let me know. The bts7960 takes current and sends it out as lower voltage logic output.

I added another schematic that is more accurate to the chip. I think i can ramp up the pwm, but I can’t test till I finish up some other wiring. I may be misunderstanding, but since the pwm has the same magnitude for pulses regardless of frequency, wouldn’t the current still spike just as high when the brush is contacting before it start rotating, whether it ramps up slow or not?

The schematic needs to be accurate to your circuit, not to the chip.
